# How to display python data frame using java script charts and flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, graph, chart.js

I have a flask route (see below) that returns a python data frame as shown:

```
         Date  SPs Left
0       Day 0      24.0
1  2020-12-04      22.0
2  2020-12-09      20.0
3  2020-12-14      18.0
4  2020-12-15       9.0
5  2020-12-16       8.0
```

```
@app.route('/burndown', methods=['GET','POST'])
def output_burndown_chart():
    if request.method == "POST":
        sprint_num = request.form['sprint_number']
        file_name = request.form['file_name']
        file_path = os.path.join("./files", file_name)
        df_final = burndown_gen(file_path, sprint_num) 
        print(df_final)
        return render_template('output_burndown.html', df_final=df_final, sprint_num=sprint_num)
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        dir_files = os.listdir('./files/')
        return render_template('burndown_form.html',dir_files=dir_files)
```

I want to make a line graph (using chart.js) out of the contents of the returned data frame with the 'Date' on the x-axis and the 'SPs Left' on the y-axis and display it from the 'output_burndown.html' template. (The 'Date' column of the data frame is of python 'date' object type)

So far, I'm just printing the data frame in table format as you can see below and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3Cqj.png):

```
<html>
<head><title>Title</title></head>
<body>
    <div align='center'>
        <h1>Burndown Table</h1>
        <h2>{{ sprint_num }}</h2>
        <table border='1', width='20%'>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>SPs Left</th>
            </tr>
            {% for index, row in df_final.iterrows(): %}
            <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center"> {{ row['Date'] }} </td>
                    <td style="text-align:center"> {{ row['SPs Left'] }} </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me on how to pass the data frame to JS and render a graph on the front end? I'm new to web programming.

Edit: I read around that I need to pass the data using 'jsonify', but I get the error that data frames are not serializable

Comment: Can you please include the output of `df_final.to_dict()`.  Post a gist or pastebin link if this is too long for the question.

Comment: @v25 Here's the output for df_final.to_dict()
[output link](https://gist.github.com/PavanRajkumar/ee20833d1938800ac20eb310a3bfc41b)

`{'Date': 
 {0: 'Day 0', 
 1: datetime.date(2020, 12, 4), 
 2: datetime.date(2020, 12, 9), 
 3: datetime.date(2020, 12, 14), 
 4: datetime.date(2020, 12, 15), 
 5: datetime.date(2020, 12, 16)}, 
'SPs Left': 
 {0: 24.0, 
 1: 22.0, 
 2: 20.0, 
 3: 18.0, 
 4: 9.0, 
 5: 8.0}}`